# DevComponents.DotNetBar.Controls.ComboBoxEx Dropdown scrolls parent form

Tags: c#, winforms

If the DevComponents.DotNetBar.Controls.ComboBoxEx Dropdown is **above another form**, the mousewheel scrolls the form in the background.

But if the Dropdown is larger and **reaches out of the parent forms area**, scrolling works fine. Everything depends on where your mouse cursor is...

Any ideas, what could be the reason / solution?